# Django "set_password()" function not working

Tags: python, django, passwords

Upon changing the password of a user on a site using Django's "set_password()" function, the password will be changed to an encrypted string. However, the user cannot log on to the site with the new password, or old - there is no previously entered password that works. Here's the snippet of code that takes the password -

```
if request.POST:
  password = request.POST['password'].encode('ascii','replace')
  confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password'].encode('ascii','replace')
  if password == confirm_password:
    user.set_password(confirm_password)
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/reset/thanks/')
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/reset/' + user.get_profile().forgotpasswordcode + "/" + user.email + "/")
```

Even when the account has the password changed to the same password that it has, the encrypted password changes and the user cannot log on.

Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `user` defined?

Comment: Why are you encoding as ASCII? When Django saves the password to the database, it's going to force unicode, so in truth, the password *doesn't* match, because the same (superficially) string in ASCII vs. Unicode is *not* the same string.

Comment: User is defined earlier on as a user object.

That was an attempt to try something new - even when staying as unicode, it doesn't match up with the new password.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the user doesn't have the `is_active` flag checked. This can lead to unusual behavior when trying to login, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to use django in-built password reset instead:

#### in urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ### previous urls
    url(r'^password/reset/$',
       auth_views.password_reset,
       {'template_name': 'my_cool_app/registration/password_reset_form.html'},
       name='my_cool_app_password_reset'),
   url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
       auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
       {'template_name': 'my_cool_app/registration/password_reset_confirm.html'},
       name='my_cool_app_password_reset_confirm'),
   url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
       auth_views.password_reset_complete,
       {'template_name': 'my_cool_app/registration/password_reset_complete.html'},
       name='my_cool_app_password_reset_complete'),
   url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
       auth_views.password_reset_done,
       {'template_name': 'my_cool_app/registration/password_reset_done.html'},
       name='my_cool_app_password_reset_done'),
    ### other urls
    )
```

You have to create the templates only and then use the url names to resolve them where needed.